# Unable to start test system 'slim': java.io.IOException: Cannot run program.. CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I am trying to execute a test case using Fitnesse but I get this error Unable to start test system 'slim': java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Java\jdk8\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long

Comment: Could you please print the full stack trace? and any chances that you are using a huge classpath when executing the test? if thats the case, look up and try this property in the Fitnesse User Guide 'CLASSPATH_PROPERTY', see whether that resolve the issue

Comment: There isn't any stack trace. I tried CLASSPATH_PROPERTY=C:/Java/jdk8/bin in the front page , as well inside the testcase. Can you please tell me where should I set this and how? The fit server starts but when running testcase I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the number of characters exceeds 255 characters. This is a NTFS filesystem limit. Reduce the number of characters in the file